# Creating an unevaluated function call with unevaluated but changing arguments

Tags: r, call

A previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22387294/creating-an-unevaluated-function-call-with-unevaluated-arguments) shows how to use `quote()` to create an unevaluated call to a function where the arguments are also unevaluated:

```
foo <-function(arg1,arg2){
  value <- arg1 + arg2
}

foocall <- call("foo",arg1=quote(x),arg2=quote(y))
foocall
# foo(arg1 = x, arg2 = y)
```

How can I keep this quality but allow the specification of arg1 to change. E.g, I have two named objects n and m in my environment and sometimes I would like to pass over one and sometimes I would like to pass over the other.

```
## Named objects
n <- c(2,3)
m <- 3

## Case 1: i would like to pass over n
z <-n
call("foo", arg1=quote(z), arg2=quote(y))

## desired output 
#foo(arg1 = n, arg2=y)

## Case 2: pass over m 
z <- m
call("foo", arg1=quote(z), arg2=quote(y))

## desired output 
#foo(arg1 = m, arg2=y)
```

I have a hard time to properly formulate my question, but I would state it like this: How can I assign to arg1 a variable that can change but doesn't evaluate 'all the way down', but only to the name of the object it is bound to?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. In both cases, when you `eval` the call the result correctly uses the values in either `n` or `m` as you've defined. (Your example would probably be simpler to use if `foo` actually returned `value`.)

Comment: My primary goal is not to evaluate but to document, in fact reproduce something like the $call list-element of an object of class lm.

Comment: Ah, so you want to display the call with all the symbols "unwrapped" down to their "original" symbol. Hm.

Comment: This seems like you are probably going down a bad R path where. If you want to track names through an analysis pipeline, you are better off explicitly doing so as a separate parameter or attribute on an object rather than requiring certain variable names in functions. It would be better to say what you are really trying to do than have us fix the "solution" you found.

Comment: This is what I would like to do. Im not trying to track names through an analysis pipeline by using a separate parameter or attribute. I would like to create an unevaluated function call with unevaluated but changing arguments. Spend some hours thinking about it. No need for fixing my 'solution', you can come up with your own or state its not possible. That would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
> z <- n
```

the right-hand side is evaluated, so the symbol `z` is assigned the *value* of `n`, not the symbol `n` itself.

```
> z
[1] 2 3
```

Now compare with

```
> z <- quote(n)
```

Now the value of `z` is a symbol, namely the symbol `n`.

```
> z
n
```

Therefore now you can do

```
> call('foo', arg1=z, arg2=quote(y))
foo(arg1 = n, arg2 = y)
```

and it will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks. But this just pushes the question just one level down. If I would do it like this I could just directly insert the `quote(n)` in the formula. Ideally I would like to assign the variable inside the quote() call. Otherwise, if i would have a 100 objects n1 to n100, I would need to hardcode 100 assignments `z <- quote(n1)` ... `z<-quote(n100)`

Comment: Yes, you're right, but there's no way around it... unless `z` is a formal argument, since function arguments in R behave in a special way.